# mysql query to php array and display the array

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM `Listing` WHERE listingid = '{$myID}'";
if(!($result2 = @ mysql_query($query2,$connection)))
    echo "query failed<br>";

$result_array = array();
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
    $result_array[] = $row2;
}
foreach ($result_array  as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```

Listing (Table) has 7 fields.
I get a bunch of "0 = Array"

How do I store mysql query results into php array and display them?
I want to have it as array first so i can sort them.

Comment: what is wrong with mysql_fetch_array (better use mysqli_fetch_array)?

Comment: @John You can start reading [here](http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases).

Comment: this is how i was taught and has been using

Comment: @ealeon Well it's bad. I also learned it like you, about 6 years ago. Time to evolve.

Comment: @ealeon mysql_* and error suppression @. You are also vulnerable to SQL injection. Please read the link I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually storing them. The code you have listed is storing them in array of arrays to see them you can modify the `for` with:

```
foreach ($result_array  as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = " .  print_r($val, true) . "\n";
}
```

$val is actually an array containing all the fields of a row.